# Изменение стилей

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Доброго времени суток коллеги, вопрос такой: 
Как изменить стиль элемента при нажатии на другой элемент?

---

Пример:
У меня есть вот такая кнопка

[image: Кнопка Google]

```
<a href="#space">
        <span class="button2">
            <span class="myfirstchar">G</span>OOGLE
        </span>
</a>
```

Как при нажатии на кнопку первая буква меняла цвет на красный(к примеру)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Еще как вариант

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 5rem;
  line-height: 5rem;
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
a:first-letter {
  color: cornflowerblue;
}
a:focus:first-letter{
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<a href="#space">
    GOOGLE
</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужно было сделать именно как кнопка но это легко исправить если в строке a:focus:first-letter заменить "focus" на "active".

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать на основе `checkbox`, безо всяких скриптов и с корректным сохранением состояния:

```css
.logo input {
    display: none
}

.logo input + label
{
    background-color: #0b0b0b;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 4px solid #065284;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 42px 0px rgba(6,82,132,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 42px 0px rgba(6,82,132,1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 42px 0px rgba(6,82,132,1);

    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font: 1.5rem sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase
}

.logo input + label span
{
    color: cornflowerblue
}

.logo input:checked + label span
{
    color: tomato
}
```

```html
<span class="logo">
    <input type="checkbox" id="logo" />
    <label for="logo"><span>G</span>oogle</label>
</span>
```

Суть состоит в том, что `checkbox` скрытно хранит состояние, влияя на страницу через стилевой псевдокласс `:checked`. Пользователь, в свою очередь, может менять это состояние через связанный `label`.

---

**Добавлено:**

Если необходимо заблокировать обратное переключение, можно организовать подмену `label` на неинтерактивный `div` при активации флажка:

```css
.logo input + label,
.logo .active
{
    background-color: #0b0b0b;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 4px solid #065284;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 42px 0px rgba(6,82,132,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 42px 0px rgba(6,82,132,1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 42px 0px rgba(6,82,132,1);

    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    font: 1.5rem sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase
}

.logo input + label
{
 cursor: pointer;
}

.logo input + label span
{
    color: cornflowerblue
}

.logo .active span
{
    color: tomato
}

/* Логика переключения */

.logo input,
.logo input:checked ~ label,
.logo input:not(:checked) ~ .active {
    display: none
}
```

```html
<span class="logo">
    <input type="checkbox" id="logo" />
    <label for="logo"><span>G</span>oogle</label>
    <div class="active"><span>G</span>oogle</div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var 
    $this = $(this),
    chart = $this.find('.myfirstchar');
  
  if(!$this.hasClass('changeColor')){
    $this.addClass('changeColor');
  } else {
    $this.removeClass('changeColor');
  }
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 5rem;
  line-height: 5rem;
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.myfirstchar {
  color: cornflowerblue;
}

.changeColor .myfirstchar {
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#space" class="btn">
        <span class="button2">
            <span class="myfirstchar">G</span>OOGLE
        </span>
</a>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/